# Can't gray the past date in calendar

Tags: html

I have this code where I tried disabling the past date but it's not working, I can't find what's causing the problem, do you have any idea what's causing this problem here's my code

```
<div id="book" class="appointment-wrapper">
    <div class="appointment">
      <div class="appointment-form">
        <form action="#">
          <h2 class="heading">Book Appointment</h2>
  
          <div class="app-field">
            <p>Name</p>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
          </div>
  
          <div class="app-field">
            <p>Date</p>
            <input type="date" id="calendar" min="2023-07-26">
          </div>
  
          <div class="app-field">
            <p>Time</p>
            <input type="time">
          </div>
  
          <div class="app-field">
            <p>Service</p>
            <select>
              <option value="service1">Service 1</option>
              <option value="service2">Service 2</option>
              <option value="service3">Service 3</option>
              <option value="service4">Service 4</option>
            </select>
          </div>
  
          <button class="btn-appointment">Book now</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get the date today by using `new Date()`.

Then pass it in your *min* input.

But you cannot get date today by just declaring on you input, isn't it?

If so, you need to do it with *javascript* and bind the value on your input.

```js
document.getElementById("calendar").min = new Date().toLocaleString('en-ZA',{year:'numeric',month:'2-digit',day:'2-digit'}).replaceAll('/','-');
```

```html
<div id="book" class="appointment-wrapper">
  <div class="appointment">
    <div class="appointment-form">
      <form action="#">
        <h2 class="heading">Book Appointment</h2>

        <div class="app-field">
          <p>Name</p>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name">
        </div>

        <div class="app-field">
          <p>Date</p>
          <input type="date" id="calendar">
        </div>

        <div class="app-field">
          <p>Time</p>
          <input type="time">
        </div>

        <div class="app-field">
          <p>Service</p>
          <select>
            <option value="service1">Service 1</option>
            <option value="service2">Service 2</option>
            <option value="service3">Service 3</option>
            <option value="service4">Service 4</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <button class="btn-appointment">Book now</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```